# Django. How display only loggedin user comments?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I want display comments from loggedin user, I tried this:

```
{% for c in request.user.game.comment_set.all %}
....
{% endfor %}
```

but doesn't work.

@edit.

Example:

User1 have comment1, comment2, User2 have comment3. 
so if I log in to User1 account, I want see only comment1, comment2

Comment: Please, clarify your question. FOR logged in user or FROM logged in user(in this case don't show comments if comment author is not online?)

Comment: User1 have comment1, comment2,
User2 have comment3.

so if I log in to User1 account, I want see only comment1, comment2

Comment: ok, Show your Game model code please

Comment: Game model? I don't have comments in game table. I have ForeignKey(Games) and ForeignKey(User) in my Comment model. 
{% for c in game.comment_set.all %} works fine, but if i add "request.user" it display nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to find user's comments in view and then pass them into your template.

views.py

```
user_comments = Comment.objects.filter(user=request.user)
return render(request, 'your_template.html', {'comments': user_comments)
```

your_template.html

```
{% for comment in comments %}
   {{ comment.message }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I see only :  Comment object Comment object Comment object 
Why?

Comment: do you have message field in Comment model or something like that? if yes then try {{ comment.message }} (updated answer)

Comment: Yes, it works. But now, If I not loggedin, I see error : 'AnonymousUser' object is not iterable.

Comment: Did you leave your old code in template? Remove it. If you removed and still have an error, can you paste template code somewhere, eg pastebin.com?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/rTfcSDtk

If I loggedin it works fine, but If I not I get error with anonymous. I think it's problem with view, but I don't know.

Comment: Code that you sent looks to be ok. It's hard to say where's the error, it can be in another part of template(I guess that you copied just a part) or in view. 
Also search for " 'AnonymousUser' object is not iterable " on stackoverflow as it's a different problem from your original question here. There are a lot of questions and answers for this problem

Comment: If I comment the line user_comments = Comment.objects.filter(author=request.user) in views.py it begin work. but I don't know how to use the is.anonymous.

Comment: It's works. I add in the view:
if request.user.is_authenticated():
  user_comments = Comment.objects.filter(author=request.user)
                thing for autheniticated
else:
    thing for anonymous

It's probably naive, but works.